# validar ingreso de datos a jTable en java netbeans

Tags: java

¿Cómo saber cuando de la base de datos no se ingrese nada a la tabla? Hago mi consulta y el resultado se ingresa a la tabla, pero cuando no se ingrese nada querrá decir que el nombre buscado no está en la base de datos. En ese momento yo quiero mandar un mensaje de que no se encuentra en la base de datos, solo que no se como hacer la validación de que no hay nada en la Jtable.

```
private void BuscarNomActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
     String[] titulos = {"NOMBRE","#                REPORTE","GRUPO","SISTEMA","FECHA","MOTIVO","SUSPENSION"};
        String[] registro = new String[7];

  DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
  Connection unaConexion = (Connection)      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/umaya", "root", "");
        java.sql.Statement instruccionSQL = unaConexion.createStatement();

        String Nomb=Nombre.getText();

        modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);

        Conexion mysql = new Conexion();
        Connection cn = mysql.Conectar();
        Statement st;

 sSQL = "SELECT nombre,numero_reporte,gradoygrupo,sistema,fecha,motivo,suspension FROM generaldb WHERE nombre LIKE '%"+Nomb+"%'";



          String cadena;
              Integer co=0;

                try {

                    st = cn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

                    while (rs.next()) {
                            String cow = rs.getString("nombre");
                     //INGRESO EL RESULTADO A MI TABLA      
                            registro[0] = rs.getString("nombre");
                            registro[1] = rs.getString("numero_reporte");
                            registro[2] = rs.getString("gradoygrupo");
                            registro[3] = rs.getString("sistema");
                            registro[4] = rs.getString("fecha");
                            registro[5] = rs.getString("motivo");
                            registro[6] = rs.getString("suspension");

                            modelo.addRow(registro);
           }
                            Tabla.setModel(modelo);
                     }
                    catch (SQLException ex) 
                    {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no se     ingreso a la base de datos ");
                    }

       }
```

Comment: agrega tu codigo para poder ayudarte con mas facilidad

Comment: ¡Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! ☺ No olvides visitar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más acerca de este sitio. Tu pregunta corre el peligro de ser cerrada como *muy amplia* ya que hay muchas soluciones para tu problema. Necesitas delimitar el espacio de solución. Tal vez quieras agregar código. En el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) encontrarás [*¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/41191/edit).

Comment: lo acabo de ingresar amigo!

Answer (score 1):

El DefaultTableModel tiene un metodo para poder saber cuantas rows (filas) tiene.
Despues del ciclo puedes preguntar por el número de filas.

```
try {

     st = cn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

     while (rs.next()) {
        String cow = rs.getString("nombre");
        //INGRESO EL RESULTADO A MI TABLA      
        registro[0] = rs.getString("nombre");
        registro[1] = rs.getString("numero_reporte");
        registro[2] = rs.getString("gradoygrupo");
        registro[3] = rs.getString("sistema");
        registro[4] = rs.getString("fecha");
        registro[5] = rs.getString("motivo");
        registro[6] = rs.getString("suspension");

        modelo.addRow(registro);
     }
     Tabla.setModel(modelo);

     if( modelo.getRowCount() == 0 )
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre buscado no existe en la Base de datos.");
     }


} catch (SQLException ex) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no se     ingreso a la base de datos ");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Después de cerrar el `while` añade lo siguiente:

```
if(model.getRowCount() == 0){
    //Lanzas el mensaje
}
```

Después de añadir todas las filas al modelo se realiza la comprobación. No es correcto que esta comprobación se añada dentro del bucle `while`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una ligera modificacion a tu codigo:

```
          String row = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
                      row = rs.getString("nombre"); // si el valor del campo no existe retorna un null, sino el valor del registro
                     //INGRESO EL RESULTADO A MI TABLA      
                            registro[0] = rs.getString("nombre");
                            registro[1] = rs.getString("numero_reporte");
                            registro[2] = rs.getString("gradoygrupo");
                            registro[3] = rs.getString("sistema");
                            registro[4] = rs.getString("fecha");
                            registro[5] = rs.getString("motivo");
                            registro[6] = rs.getString("suspension");

                            modelo.addRow(registro);
           }
               if(row != null) Tabla.setModel(modelo);
```

Comment: En que consiste la modificació y que puede ayudar?